# limit number of fetched results per category to only 4 than display "See More Results"

Tags: php, mysql

running into a problem yet again and need some help with solving it.

I need to limit the number of retrieved results in each category that has any results at all to display only 4 and below category will be displaying link to the category such as "See more Results" or similar.

My initial thought was that I need to either change or add something to the actual query it self so I did add LIMIT 4, but the outcome of this was that I ended up with only one category being displayed  with 4 items within that category and this was it.

Please help

here is my script

```
if($category_type == 'links_only'){
    $category_topic_query = 'SELECT l.category_name, l.category_folder, l.category_page, f.parentpageID, f.ImagePath, f.referring_url, f.templateTitle, f.xls, f.xlsx, f.ots, f.gdocs, f.numbers, f.templateImage, f.templimgwidth, f.templimgheight FROM lcategories l INNER JOIN Files f ON f.parentpageID = l.ID WHERE f.pageID = "0" ORDER BY f.parentpageID';
    $resc = $db->prepare($category_topic_query);
    $resc->execute();
$last_topic = NULL;
$add_rowNum = 1;
while ($category_topic = $resc -> fetch()){
    $category_topic_ID = $category_topic['parentpageID'];
    if($category_topic_ID !== $last_topic) {
        $add_rowNum++;
    $category_topic_name = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $category_topic['category_name']);
    $category_topic_url = DST.$category_topic['category_folder'].DS.$category_topic['category_page'];
    $divider_div = ($add_rowNum % 2 == 0) ? '
<div class="clear"></div>' : FALSE ;
    $first_ul = ($category_topic_ID == 1) ? FALSE : '</ul>
</div>'.$divider_div ;
print<<<END
$first_ul
<div style="float: left; margin: 10px; width: 349px;">
<h2 class="h_unln"><a href="$category_topic_url">$category_topic_name</a></h2>
<ul class="arrow">

END;

$last_topic = $category_topic_ID;
}
    $links_array = ($category_topic['referring_url'] == NULL) ? FALSE :'
    <li>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="'.DST.$category_topic['ImagePath'].DS.$category_topic['referring_url'].'"><img src="'.$image_path.$category_topic['ImagePath'].DS.$category_topic['templateImage'].'" width="'.$category_topic['templimgwidth'].'" height="'.$category_topic['templimgheight'].'" title="'.$category_topic['templateTitle'].'"></a></li>
    <li><a href="'.DST.$category_topic['ImagePath'].DS.$category_topic['referring_url'].'">'.$category_topic['templateTitle'].'</a></li>
    <li>'.$numbers_im.$gdocs_im.$ots_im.$xlsx_im.$xls_im.'</li></ul></li>';


print<<<END
$links_array

END;
}
print<<<END
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

END;
}
```

Comment: Its called pagination.

Comment: Ok, and how do I have to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $limit = ($_GET['limit'])? $_GET['limit'] : 4 ; //For the first query only 4 links will be displayed
    $offset = ($_GET['offset'])? $_GET['offset'] : 0;
```

Adjust your query like this:

```
$category_topic_query = "SELECT l.category_name, l.category_folder, l.category_page, f.parentpageID, f.ImagePath, f.referring_url, f.templateTitle, f.xls, f.xlsx, f.ots, f.gdocs, f.numbers, f.templateImage, f.templimgwidth, f.templimgheight FROM lcategories l INNER JOIN Files f ON f.parentpageID = l.ID WHERE f.pageID = '0' ORDER BY f.parentpageID 
LIMIT  $limit OFFSET $offset";
```

Then in your 'see more link'

```
<a href='<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?limit=20&offset=4'> See more </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this method won't work it limits number of categories on that page to only 1 with 4 items displayed within.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like scroll pagination which will generate more results as you scroll just like facebook/twitter
see here
[jquery scroll pagination](http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/)

Also see [jquery scroll pagination + php](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-jquery-scroll-paging-with-php_294.html)

Comment: I think I will have to amend my question, what I meant basically is not related to pagination at all, basically if you follow the link to http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/templates/?CTT=97 you will see what I meant. there are categories with 5 images in each one of them, so I need similar thing on my clients site, but cannot figure out how to limit results from table "Files" to only bring up first 4 on each cycle and in each category.

Comment: Why dont you just write 2 sqls 1.To get categories then loop through it to get the results(you can limit here) and then display the link showing 'see more results' if results are more than 4

Comment: I thought of this too, but just trying to figure out how, meaning what will go where in the query to get desired results